# React.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I m not sure how can i explain it. But i will do my best. I'm developing a Movie App. I dont have problem about receiving data and viewing it on the screen. Besides i can see my errors on screen like "Too Many Results" but it's working only on main page. When i'm doing my searching like only series. I have another page for it. I dont have problem about receiving data and viewing it on the screen. But i cant see my error codes.

Fetch Page

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const API_ENDPOINT = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=
${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API_KEY}`

 const useFetch = (urlParams) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isError, setError] = useState({show:false, msg:''});
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
    const fetchMovies = async (url) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
  if(data.Response === 'True' ){
    setData(data.Search || data);
    setError({show:false,msg: '' });
  }
  else if(data.Response=== null){
    setError({show:true,msg:data.Error})
  }
  else{
    setError({show:true,msg:data.Error})
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(`${API_ENDPOINT}&s=${urlParams}`) 
  },[urlParams])
    return {isLoading, isError, data }
}

export default useFetch;
```

Context page

```
import React, { useState, useContext} from 'react'
import useFetch from '../useFetch';

export const API_ENDPOINT = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API_KEY}`

const AppContext = React.createContext()
const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('spider-man');
  const [hero, setHero] = useState('batman');
  const [vero, setVero] = useState('high-score');
  const [games, setGames] = useState('game');
  const [dizi, setDizi] = useState('series');
  const {isLoading,isError,data:movies } = useFetch(`&s=${query}`);
  
  return <AppContext.Provider value={{isLoading,isError,movies,query,setQuery,dizi, setDizi,games, setGames, hero, setHero,vero, setVero}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext)
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

SearchFormType page

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/context';


const SearchFormType = () => {
  const {vero, setVero,isError} = useGlobalContext();
  
  return (
  <form className="search-form" onSubmit={(e)=>
  e.preventDefault}>
    <h2>Search Series</h2>
    <input type="text " className="form-input" value={vero}
    onChange={(e)=> setVero(e.target.value)}/>
    {isError.show && <div className='error'>{isError.msg}</div>}
    </form>
  )
}

export default SearchFormType;
```

Series page

```
    import React from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/context';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import useFetch from '../useFetch';
const url =
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/No_picture_available.png'

const Series = () => {
  const {vero,dizi} = useGlobalContext();
  
  const {isLoading,data:movies } = useFetch(`&s=${vero}&type=${dizi}`);
  
  if(isLoading){
    return <div className='loading'></div>
  }
 
return <section className="movies">
{movies.map((movie)=>{
  const {imdbID: key, Poster:poster, Title:title, Year:year} =
  movie
  return <Link to= {`/series/${key}`} key ={key} className="movie">
    <article>
      <img src={poster === 'N/A'? url : poster} alt={title} />
      <div className="movie-info">
        <h4 className="title">{title}</h4>
        <p>{year}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </Link>
  
})}</section>
}

export default Series;
```

I don't know if it's necessary but My home page

```
import React, { useContext }  from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/context'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const url =
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/No_picture_available.png'

const Movies = () => {

  const { movies ,isLoading} = useGlobalContext();
  
  
  if(isLoading){
    return <div className='loading'></div>
  }
  

return <section className="movies">
 
{movies.map((movie)=>{
  const {imdbID: key, Poster:poster, Title:title, Year:year} =
  movie
  return (
    
  <Link to= {`/movies/${key}`} key ={key} className="movie">
    <article>
      <img src={poster === 'N/A'? url : poster} alt={title} />
      <div className="movie-info">
        <h4 className="title">{title}</h4>
        <p>{year}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </Link>
 
  )
 
})}</section>
}

export default Movies;
```

for last My main SearchForm

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/context';

const SearchForm = () => {
  const {query, setQuery,isError} = useGlobalContext();
  
  return (
  <form className="search-form" onSubmit={(e)=>
  e.preventDefault}>
    <h2>Search Movies</h2>
    <input type="text " className="form-input" value={query}
    onChange={(e)=> setQuery(e.target.value)}/>
    {isError.show && <div className='error'>{isError.msg}</div>}
    </form>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

Comment: I think i m getting these errors because i cant call my error codes to my series page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message, it says you're trying to call `.map()` on `null` value. In your code there's two places where it could be:

```
movies.map((movie) => {
  ...
})
```

Even if you're having trouble getting stack traces, you can figure out which spot is causing the error by logging the value of `movies`.

```
if (movies === null) {
  console.error('oh no, movies is null');
}
```

It's possible that global context starts off with `null` movies or `useFetch` defaults to `null` movies while the request is pending.

Comment: i figured out the spot its Search page but i m using an error code on Fetch page like    these: `else if(data.Response=== null){ setError({show:true,msg:data.Error}) }`  My real question is why its not working.

Answer (score -2):

You just need a unique API key.

Go to http://www.omdbapi.com/apikey.aspx

request and activate an API key.

This line in Context page file

```
export const API_ENDPOINT = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API_KEY}`
```

Should now look like this:

```
const API_ENDPOINT = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${"place your activated key here"}`;
```

Note: In a production, it is better to place API secret keys in the .env file for security reasons.

Comment: You've recommended they make a change that they remove the API key from env vars, then say they should use env vars. Also, the API key doesn't look to be the problem as they see results elsewhere.